# Oracle sql query: pivot table with dynamicly filled for in (advanced)

Tags: oracle, dynamic, pivot

I need to flatten an table, but here si the tricky part, the clomuns are dynamic and the query should work when new records are added containing a new ID.

This is my working query (simplified the IN this is really hundreds of values):

```
SELECT *
FROM   (select qv.respnr, sq.question_id, qv.question_value
from survey_question sq, question_values qv
where qv.question_id = sq.question_id
and sq.survey_id = 1
order by qv.respnr, page, ranked)
PIVOT (
MAX(question_value)        --<-- pivot_clause
FOR question_id          --<-- pivot_for_clause
IN (346 as c346,347 as c347)
)
```

I want to replace the `IN (346 as c346,347 as c347)` with something like this:

```
SELECT mq.question_id
  FROM meta_question mq, survey_question sq2
 WHERE sq2.survey_id = 1
   AND mq.question_id = sq2.question_id
 ORDER BY page, ranked
```

Any idea how to do this?

I've noticed the IN can't be simply fileld with a select statement, so this doesn't work:

```
IN (SELECT mq.question_id
      FROM meta_question mq, survey_question sq2
     WHERE sq2.survey_id = 1
       AND mq.question_id = sq2.question_id
     ORDER BY page, ranked)
```

Answer (score 2):

The name and type of all columns in SQL needs to be known at compile time, here you will have to use [dynamic SQL](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#CACDDACH) since you want the number of columns to change *depending upon the data*.

If you use PL/SQL, you can use a [ref cursor](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#i13057):

```
DECLARE
   l_rc            SYS_REFCURSOR;
   l_dynamic_query VARCHAR2(32000);
BEGIN
   FOR cc IN (SELECT mq.question_id
                FROM meta_question mq, survey_question sq2
               WHERE sq2.survey_id = 1
                 AND mq.question_id = sq2.question_id
               ORDER BY page, ranked) LOOP
      -- build dynamic query here
   END LOOP;
   OPEN l_rc FOR '
      SELECT *
        FROM (SELECT qv.respnr, sq.question_id, qv.question_value
                FROM survey_question sq, question_values qv
               WHERE qv.question_id = sq.question_id
                 AND sq.survey_id = 1
               ORDER BY qv.respnr, page, ranked) 
               PIVOT ( MAX (question_value) --<-- pivot_clause
                       FOR question_id --<-- pivot_for_clause
                        IN (' || l_dynamic_query || ')
                      )';
    -- process l_rc (LOOP..FETCH..CLOSE)
END;
```

You can also use [`DBMS_SQL`](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/dynamic.htm#BHCIBJBG).

Answer (score 1):

Since the columns in a `pivot` must be known, you will need to use dynamic SQL to generate the result.  I typically generate a procedure using a ref_cursor to perform this task similar to this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE procedure dynamic_pivot_q(p_cursor in out sys_refcursor)
as
    sql_query varchar2(8000) := 'select qv.respnr ';

    begin
        for x in (select distinct question_id, mname from meta_question order by 1)
        loop
            sql_query := sql_query ||
                ' , max(case when mq.question_id = '||x.question_id||' then qv.question_value else null end) as "c'||x.mname||'"';

                dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);
        end loop;

        sql_query := sql_query || ' from meta_question mq  
                                    left join survey_question sq 
                                      on mq.question_id = sq.question_id  
                                      and sq.survey_id = 1  
                                    inner join question_values qv 
                                      on qv.question_id = sq.question_id 
                                      and sq.survey_id = 1 
                                    group by qv.respnr';

        dbms_output.put_line(sql_query);

        open p_cursor for sql_query;
    end;
/
```

Then you can execute it the following way (*note: this is the code I use in TOAD*):

```
variable x refcursor
exec dynamic_pivot_q(:x)
print x
```