# Divide Query result to columns

Tags: sql, oracle

I have db, and I have such query:

```
SELECT createdate, count(id)
FROM table_name
GROUP BY createdate;
```

Result is shown as:

> ```
> createdate | count(id)
>   -------------------------
>   01-Jan-2014    50    
>   02-Jan-2014    40
>     -             -
>  -------------------------
> ```

But I want the result could be shown as:

> ```
>     createdate| 01-Jan-2014| 02-Jan-2014| -
>    -----------------------------------------
>     count(id) | 50         | 40         | -
> ```

Is it possible? Can you help me?

Comment: So, is it `Oracle` or `MySQL`?

Comment: It's oracle, but if any ideas on mysql, I dont mind,

Comment: The answer would be different since `Oracle` has [`PIVOT`](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/sql/11g-pivot-097235.html) and `MySQL` doesn't.

Comment: Ok, I have db on Oracle, I want the answer in Oracle

Comment: Did you follow the link in my comment?

Comment: PM 77-1! Thank you very much, Pivot is what I wanted :) thank you again.

Comment: PM 77-1! can I ask you?! I did pivot such:
`select * from (select createdate, count(id) from table_name group by createdate) pivot (count(id) for creaetdate in ('01-Jan-2014')`.

Comment: Can I input to `in ()` dynamically, not by typing each date? Is it possible

Comment: What's expected to happen if additional rows with other dates are added to the table?

Comment: because I have many rows with dates, and it's uncomfortable to type them manually

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15092976/2055998).